# Cannot create simple cache with Caffeine

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

I'm trying to create a simple (non-loading) cache with Caffeine.

```
Cache<String, MyObject> countsCache =   
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
```

This fails to compile, with the Error reported:

```
Error:(42, 31) java: incompatible types: 
no instance(s) of type variable(s) K1,V1 exist so that org.elasticsearch.common.cache.Cache<K1,V1> conforms to com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache<java.lang.String,com.foo.bar.MyObject>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that you imported the ElasticSearch's Cache interface to assign to the result of the cache builder. The builder syntax you showed is Guava's `CacheBuilder`. Because many users would have Guava and might migrate, the builder is called `Caffeine` to reduce confusion.

You should be able to construct a cache like,

```
Cache<String, MyObject> countsCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build();
```